# Multiple inheritance cast not working as expected

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, dynamic-cast, reinterpret-cast

I recently had a problem with casts and multiple inheritance: I needed to cast a `Base*` to `Unrelated*`, because a specific `Derived` class derives the `Unrelated` class.

This is a short example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base{
    virtual ~Base() = default; 
};

struct Unrelated{
    float test = 111;    
};

struct Derived : Base,Unrelated{};

int main(){
    Base* b = new Derived;
    Unrelated* u1 = (Unrelated*)b;
    std::cout << u1->test << std::endl; //outputs garbage
    Unrelated* y = dynamic_cast<Unrelated*>(b);
    std::cout << y->test << std::endl; //outputs 111
}
```

The first cast clearly doesnt work, but the second one did work.
My question is: Why did the second cast work? Shouldnt `dynamic_cast` only work for cast to a related class type? I thought there wasnt any information about `Unrelated` at runtime because it is not polymorphic.

Edit: I used colirus gcc for the example.

Comment: You keep pointer to Derived instance in b and you are casting it to Unrelated from which you inherit. What's the problem?

Comment: `Unrelated` is a base of `Derived` and you are up-casting from `Derived*` to `Unrelated*` which is why this is valid.

Comment: Eek. C style casts. Don't use them. Use the correct C++style cast instead - always.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dynamic_cast` works because the *dynamic type* of object pointed to by a pointer to its base class is related to `Unrelated`.

Keep in mind that `dynamic_cast` requires a virtual table to inspect the inheritance tree of the object at run-time.

The C-style cast `(Unrelated*)b` does not work because [the C-style cast does `const_cast`, `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` and more, but it does not do `dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast).

I would suggest avoiding C-style casts in C++ code because they do so many things as opposed to precise C++ casts. My colleagues who insist on using C-style cast still occasionally get them wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The first cast `(Unrelated*)b` doesn't work because you're treating the `Base` class sub-object, containing probably just a vtable pointer, as an `Unrelated`, containing a `float`.

Instead you can cast down and up, `static_cast<Unrelated*>( static_cast<Derived*>( b ) )`.

And  this is what `dynamic_cast` does for you, since `Base` is a polymorphic type (at least one virtual method) which allows `dynamic_cast` to inspect the type of the most derived object.

In passing, `dynamic_cast<void*>( b )` would give you a pointer to the most derived object.

However, since you know the types there's no need to invoke the slight overhead of a `dynamic_cast`: just do the down- and up-casts.

---

Instead of the **C style cast** `(Unrelated*)b` you should use the corresponding C++ **named cast** or casts, because C style *casts of pointers* can do things you'd not expect, and because the effect can change completely when types are changed during maintenance.

The C style cast will maximum do 2 C++ named casts. In this case the C style cast corresponds to a `reinterpret_cast`. The compiler will not allow any other named cast here.

Which is a warning sign. ;-)

In contrast, the down- and up-casts are `static_cast`s, which usually are benign casts.

---

All that said, the best is to almost completely avoid casts by using the top secret technique:

*Don't throw away type information in the first place.*

I.e., in the example code, just use `Derived*` as the type of the pointer.

Comment: While I wholeheartedly agree with your last sentence, it also means *don't do polymoprhism*.

Answer (score 2):

With multiple inheritance, the `Derived` object consists of two sub-objects, one `Base` and one `Unrelated`. The compiler knows how to access whichever part of the object it needs, typically by adding an offset to the pointer (but that's an implementation detail). It can *only* do that when it knows the actual type of a pointer. By using a C-style cast, you've told the compiler to ignore the actual type and treat that pointer value as a pointer to something else. It no longer has the information necessary to properly access the sub-object you desire, and it fails.

`dynamic_cast` allows the compiler to use run-time information about the object to locate the proper sub-object contained within it. If you were to output or examine the pointer values themselves, you'd see that they are different.